# Where to place Git repository

Tags: ruby-on-rails, git, version-control

I just started using Git and I want to know if this is the right way of using it. I started a Rails app with:

```
rails newapp
```

Then I did:

```
cd newapp
git init
git add .
git commit -a
```

So is it "right" to init my git inside my working directory?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Yes. You can place a git repository *anywhere* - including the invisible .git directory created by another git repository. I have a friend who has git track all his system config files in case he makes a mistake.

When working on a project, you want to init your repository in the root directory of the project.

To elaborate, each "working copy" of a Git repository *is itself a Git repository.* If you have a remote copy on a server, that is also a repository. You don't "check out" from there - rather, you "push" your changes and they are merged. If working on a purely personal project, the remote repository is often unnecessary. If you do want to host remotely, [Github](http://github.com/) is a good, free, public choice.

Comment: OK, so unlike SVN, I will have a Git repository for EACH project?

In SVN, I usually have a repository somewhere away from my projects, and then I check in all my projects into that repository.

Comment: That’s exactly the way it is, alamodey.

Comment: one repository for one project is the way to use distributed version control system (of which Git is an example)

Answer (score 0):

Yep. Looks good to me.

Answer (score 0):

Yes. In a DCVS like git, your working copy *is* your repository.

Comment: The working copy is not the repository - at least, not to my way of thinking.  The stuff under the .git directory is the repository, isn't it?

Comment: Well, yes. But they can't be in completely distinct places, like in centralized versioning systems such as Subversion and CVS. Also, in git it is possible to have a 'bare' repository without a working copy, but I didn't want to mention that.